# How to get Select max value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller:**

```
$next_id = $this->o->next_id();
$data['next_id']=$next_id;
```

**Model:**

```
public function next_id(){
    $this->db->select_max('p_ori_id');
    $max = $this->db->get('orientation_master');
    if($max==0){
        $next_id = 1;
    }else{
        $next_id = 1+$max;
    }
    return $next_id;
}
```

**Return Error:**

> Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Please solve problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No offense to @pradeep but you may have some unexpected results if you don't have any rows. I suggest:

```
public function next_id()
{
   $this->db->select_max('p_ori_id', 'max');
   $query = $this->db->get('orientation_master');
   if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
      return 1;
   }
   $max = $query->row()->max;
   return $max == 0 ? 1 : $max + 1;
}
```

Comment: i' m so stupid i even answer to such askers, thanks to you, you just open    my eyes

Comment: what do you mean  by No offense to @pradeep, you know it is

Comment: so only you can see that angle, we r here  to provide only some hints to probrammer by giving simple solution, not write to logic or what u say a different angle , i know u didn't force , only answer to the question which already have an accepted answer, by the way thank you again

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this will help you:**

```
public function next_id()
{
   $this->db->select_max('p_ori_id', 'max');
   $query = $this->db->get('orientation_master'); 
   // Produces: SELECT MAX(p_ori_id) as max FROM orientation_master
   $max = $query->row()->max;
   if($max == 0){
     $next_id = 1;
   }else{
     $next_id = $max+1;
  }
  return $next_id;
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error becuase `$max` is a result set object and not an integer record value like you're trying to use it.

You can try this function to get the next id.

**Modified function:**

```
public function next_id(){
    $this->db->select_max('p_ori_id', 'max');
    $result = $this->db->get('orientation_master');
    $row = $result->row_array();
    $next_id = isset($row['max']) ? ($row['max']+1) : 1;
    return $next_id;
}
```

If the column is auto increment, you can use the below code instead.

**Alternative:**

```
public function next_id() {
        $sql_string = "SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = '".$this->db->dbprefix."orientation_master'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql_string);
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row['auto_increment'];
    }
```